# How to disable automatic colors in the Twenty Twenty theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-customizer

I'm using the Twenty Twenty theme to create a website, and I want to totally disable the automatic colors that Wordpress generates based on the accent hue. I have very specific branding guidelines to follow, and I can't have automatically generated colors appear out of nowehere. Manually overriding this stuff with CSS !important everywhere it appears is just ugly, so I was wondering if it's possible to do it in a more elegant way. And also, where can I enter specific RGB values for the accent color, instead of relying on the hue slider?

Answer (score 4):

Building on the answer from Aristeides, here is a complete working code example of using the `theme_mod_acccent_accessible_colours` filter. This is tested and working in version 1.1 of TwentyTwenty and version 5.3.2 of WordPress.

You can place this code in your `functions.php` file and change the colours in the array to what you'd like. In the code shown below I have changed the 'accent' colour to a dark purple (#7f5871).

```
/* Hook into the colours added via the customiser. */
add_filter( 'theme_mod_accent_accessible_colors', 'op_change_default_colours', 10, 1 );

/**
 * Override the colours added in the customiser.
 *
 * @param array $default An array of the key colours being used in the theme.
 */
function op_change_default_colours( $default ) {

    $default = array(
        'content'       => array(
            'text'      => '#000000',
            'accent'    => '#7f5871',
            'secondary' => '#6d6d6d',
            'borders'   => '#dcd7ca',
        ),
        'header-footer' => array(
            'text'      => '#000000',
            'accent'    => '#7f5871',
            'secondary' => '#6d6d6d',
            'borders'   => '#dcd7ca',
        ),
    );

    return $default;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I was about to dismiss and bin this theme. Why don't they just add these colors as options to the customizer?

Answer (score 0):

I had never used this theme until I read your question, so I decided to install it to see what you're talking about.

I'm with you, not a fan of the auto colors, what a horrible idea.  They say its for usability.  You can [read about it HERE](https://github.com/WordPress/twentytwenty/issues/284).

To answer your question, there is no built in way to change the colors, besides what you have already been doing.  There also isn't a way to enter a specific color value for the primary color slider.

You could however create a child theme and add your own [customizer options](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API).  This would be more work then just manually overriding them in CSS like your doing.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty easy... You can use a filter on `theme_mod_accent_accessible_colors`. You can see how the option is formatted here: 
https://github.com/WordPress/twentytwenty/blob/master/functions.php#L636

Answer (score 0):

You may lookup the filter-call `return apply_filters( 'twentytwenty_get_elements_array', $elements );` in functions.php then comment it out.